# Java timeformat and time duration

Tags: java, time

Output I need is this:

Time in: 07:00 AM

Time out: 11:30 PM

Time duration: 16 hours and 30 minutes

User needs to enter in time in and time out, How do I do it? I searched and it seems that I need DateFormat hh:mm: a but I don't know how to use it. Help please. thanks.

Comment: Add a code example. What do you do so far?

Comment: You might want to have a look at: http://www.mkyong.com/java/how-to-calculate-date-time-difference-in-java/

Comment: `System.out.print("Time In: ");
timein=n.readLine();`

Answer (score 0):

```
DateFormat dateFormat = new SimpleDateFormat("hh:mm a");

long timeIn = dateFormat.parse("07:00 AM").getTime();
long timeOut = dateFormat.parse("11:30 PM").getTime();

long duration = (timeOut - timeIn) / 1000 / 60;   // in minutes
long hours = duration / 60;
long minutes = duration % 60;

System.out.println("Time duration: " + hours + " hours and " + minutes + " minutes");
```

Prints:

> Time duration: 16 hours and 30 minutes

Comment: `System.out.print("Time In: ");
  timein_a=n.readLine();
  timeIn = dateFormat.parse(timein_a).getTime();
  System.out.print(timeIn);` I'm getting error, unreported exception ParseException; must be caught or declared to be thrown

Comment: @Shivr You need wrap it by 'try-catch' or add 'throws ParseException' to method's signature.

Answer (score 0):

You can trying something like this:

```
import java.text.DateFormat;
import java.text.SimpleDateFormat;
import java.util.Calendar;
import java.util.Date;


public class TimeTracker {

    static Date getTimeIn() {
        //There you must to use your specific Time In getting from user
        //It's just example
        Calendar calendarIn = Calendar.getInstance();

        calendarIn.set(Calendar.HOUR_OF_DAY, 7);
        calendarIn.set(Calendar.MINUTE, 00);
        calendarIn.set(Calendar.SECOND, 0);
        calendarIn.set(Calendar.MILLISECOND, 0 );

        return calendarIn.getTime();
    }

    static Date getTimeOut() {
        //There you must to use your specific Time In getting from user
        //It's just example
        Calendar calendarOut = Calendar.getInstance();

        calendarOut.set(Calendar.HOUR_OF_DAY, 23);
        calendarOut.set(Calendar.MINUTE, 30);
        calendarOut.set(Calendar.SECOND, 0);
        calendarOut.set(Calendar.MILLISECOND, 0);

        return calendarOut.getTime();
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) throws InterruptedException {

        DateFormat formatterTime = new SimpleDateFormat("hh:mm a");
        long timeDuration = getTimeOut().getTime() - getTimeIn().getTime();
        System.out.println("Time in: " + formatterTime.format(getTimeIn()));
        System.out.println("Time out: " + formatterTime.format(getTimeOut()));
        System.out.println("Time duration: " + 
            ((timeDuration / (1000*60*60)) % 24) 
                + " hours and " + 
                    ((timeDuration / (1000*60)) % 60) + " minutes");
     }
}
```

Output is:

> Time in: 07:00 AM
>
> Time out: 11:30 PM
>
> Time duration: 16 hours and 30 minutes

Answer (score 0):

Hi you can try something like this

```
   public String timeDifference(String timeIn,String timeOut){ 
    DateFormat dateFormat=new SimpleDateFormat("hh:mm a");
            String result;
            Date d=dateFormat.parse("08:14 AM");   //First input time in
            Date d1=dateFormat.parse("09:00 PM");   //second input time out

            long min=TimeUnit.MINUTES.convert(d1.getTime()-d.getTime(),TimeUnit.MILLISECONDS);
            System.out.println(min);
            if(min>=60){
                long hrs=min/60;
                result=String.valueOf(min/60)+" hours "+String.valueOf(min%60)+" minutes";

            }
            else
                result=min+" minutes";

            System.out.println(result);
return result;
}
```

Comment: 8:14 AM and 09:00 PM are the timeIn and timeOut respectively